# Don't know how to assign variable to my interface objects

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I've done a software that I use with the command prompt but I want to make it easier to use with an interface so I'm trying to make a javafx program. I have the interface done and I can run it but I don't know how to start to assign my object (combobox, button, textfield...) to a variable.
Does anybody can help me with it ? 
My interface have been done with Scene builder.
Here is my main class :

```
    package ch.makery.adress;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;


    public class MainApp extends Application {



        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
            Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("PersonOverview.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
            stage.setTitle("Appication Extraction dar et remplissage Excel");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();


    }
    }
```

And here is my controller class wich obvisouly is not right. I'm trying to make a combobox work but I can't find the variable in Scene Builder :

```
package ch.makery.adress;

import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class HexaController implements Initializable {

        @FXML
        private ComboBox<String> hexa;
        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();




        @FXML
        private void parcourir(ActionEvent event){

        }


        @FXML
        private ComboBox<Integer>methode;

private MainApp MainApp;

public HexaController(){

}

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
    list.add(new String("OUI"));
    list.add(new String("NON"));
    hexa.setItems(list);

}
}
```

I don't know what's missing or what i did wrong.

Thanks

**Edit**
I have acces to my variable in Scene Builder so i'm able to have access to my ComboBox List. 
Now I have to find a way to select a file when I click on a button, and write the path of it on a TextField (Don't know if it's the best way to do it but I have to open a file that will be copy). I also have to find a way to access to the user choice in my Main app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a controller. Once you created your controller, in SceneBuilder, you will be able to assign the controller to your fxml by going on the left side, clicking on the controller menu and specifiying the controller class.

In your controller class itself, you will declare your variable using @FXML prefix. Exemple on how to declare a ComboBox in your controller:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class MyPageController
{
    @FXML
    private ComboBox _myComboBox;
}
```

Once you've saved, you can go back to SceneBuilder, select your ComboBox and on the right side, click on "Code" and you will be able to specify the element's fx:id

**edit**
You edited your question showing your code, so part of my answer doesn't make sense anymore

Comment: Thanks a lot it's a first step done I can access to my variable on my combobox. Now I'm trying to set my combobox list.

Comment: I have my ComboBox list when I run it perfect !

Comment: Glad it helped! But concerning your question edit, you shouldn't do that, let the original question and ask another one, for the sake of future readers